# SVN Post-Commit not working

Tags: bash, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Blue Host and was setting up my SVN and I have been able to set up and checkout repositories perfectly fine, but when I've tried to setup a post-commit, I keep getting the error

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.
```

Here is the current post-commit hook that I'm using

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/svn update /home1/firewal2/www/svntest
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more information if needed. Thanks!

-Blake

Comment: Is the post-commit-script executable? Can you execute it in the terminal?

Comment: @Gregor I do, and then it prompts me with   

Enter passphrase for key '/home1/firewal2/.ssh/id_dsa':  

and I can't figure out what to put in the post-commit to make it verify the passphrase

Comment: Your post-commit script cannot enter a passphrase for you. You will have to create a public key without a passphrase - because the post-commit script will run unattended.

Comment: So just change from a private to a public key?

Comment: You need a private key without a passphrase. Read more on this topic in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114012/svn-ssh-without-password-from-command-line

Comment: Using a public key worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Your post-commit script cannot enter a passphrase for you. You will have to create a public key without a passphrase - because the post-commit script will run unattended. – Gregor

You need a private key without a passphrase. Read more on this topic in [stackoverflow.com/questions/5114012/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114012/svn-ssh-without-password-from-command-line) – Gregor