# Making scripte answering svn+ssh passkey

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn, ssh

I have a shell scripte that i have to configure for updating some svn repository set up with crontab in order to backup the repository on an other machine.

The thing is one of the repository is protected with an key which is password protected.

I'd like to make the scripte automatically answering the question, and i don't know how to do this.

I already tried the "yes  | svn co svn+ssh... " and it doesn't seems to be working.
Is there a way to make the scripte answering it, or simply juste stop svn from asking the password by storing it somewhere?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

That would only be possible if you have launched first an ssh-agent.

See for instance "[svn + ssh without password from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5114012/6309)", and [this tutorial](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh#run-ssh-agent).

The first connection will ask for the passphrase and register it.
The other connections won't ask for the passphrase at all.